# OpenCL: Access neighbors error

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I'm working on a solver for a differential equation for a particle smulation using Pyopencl.
To solve this equation each particle must access it's neighbors information.
The arrays I'm using are numpy complex64 arrays each with 7 elements.

When accessing the neighbors, the program returns the error:

```
clWaitForEvents failed: out of resources
```

My OpenCl code is the following. I guess most of it isn't related to this error but i'll post it anyway because it might help somehow:

```
#define complex_ctr(x, y) (float2)(x, y)
#define complex_add(a, b) complex_ctr((a).x + (b).x, (a).y + (b).y)
#define complex_mul(a, b) complex_ctr(mad(-(a).y, (b).y, (a).x * (b).x), mad((a).y, (b).x, (a).x * (b).y))
#define complex_mul_scalar(a, b) complex_ctr((a).x * (b), (a).y * (b))
#define complex_div_scalar(a, b) complex_ctr((a).x / (b), (a).y / (b))
#define conj(a) complex_ctr((a).x, -(a).y)
#define conj_transp(a) complex_ctr(-(a).y, (a).x)
#define conj_transp_and_mul(a, b) complex_ctr(-(a).y * (b), (a).x * (b))
#define complex_real(a) a.x
#define complex_imag(a) a.y
#define complex_unit (float2)(0, 1)

constant int M=10; 
constant float L=1e-09; 
constant float p0=1.0; 
constant float delta=1.0; 
constant float gama=1.0; 
constant float omc=1.0;  
constant float k_p=1.0; 
constant float om_p=1.0;
constant float v = 0.001; 
constant float b = 1.0;
constant float dt=0.01; 

void f(__global float2 *X,  
       __global float2 *K, 
       int id, 
       uint W,
       float t){  
    float exp_arg;
    float2 p11, p22, p33, p21, p31, p32, op, aux, ar, al, p;
    p11 = X[id*W];
    p22 = X[id*W+1];
    p33 = X[id*W+2];
    p21 = X[id*W+3];
    p31 = X[id*W+4];
    p32 = X[id*W+5];
    al = X[(id-1)*W+6];
    ar = X[(id+1)*W+6];
    op = p0 * complex_mul(X[id*W+6], complex_unit);

    aux = p22 * gama/2 + complex_mul(op, p22) + conj(p22) * gama/2 + complex_mul(op, conj(p22));
    K[id*W] = aux;

    aux = (-p22*gama - complex_mul(op, p21) + complex_mul(p32, complex_unit)*omc 
          - conj(p22)*gama - complex_mul(op, conj(p21)) + complex_mul(conj(p32), complex_unit)*omc);
    K[id*W+1] = aux;

    aux = p22*gama/2 - complex_mul(p32, complex_unit)*omc + conj(p22)*gama/2 - complex_mul(conj(p32), complex_unit)*omc;
    K[id*W+2] = aux;

    aux = complex_mul(op, p11) - complex_mul(op, p22) - p21*gama + complex_mul(p21, complex_unit)*delta + complex_mul(p31, complex_unit)*omc;    
    K[id*W+3] = aux;

    aux = complex_mul(p21, complex_unit)*omc + complex_mul(p31, complex_unit)*delta - complex_mul(op, p32);
    K[id*W+4] = aux;

    aux = (complex_mul(p22, complex_unit)*omc - complex_mul(p33, complex_unit)*omc - complex_mul(op, p31) - p32*gama);
    K[id*W+5] = aux;

    exp_arg = k_p * L * id - om_p * t;
    p = complex_mul(b*p0*p21*complex_ctr(cos(exp_arg), sin(exp_arg)), complex_unit);
    aux = (X[(id-1)*W+6] + X[(id+1)*W+6]);
    aux = aux + p;
    K[id*W+6] = aux;
}

__kernel void RK4Step(__global float2 *X, 
                      __global float2 *K, 
                      __global float2 *Xs, 
                      __global float2 *Xm, 
                      uint W,
                      float t){
    const int gid_x = get_global_id(0);
    int idx = 0;    

    //computation of k1
    f(X, K, gid_x, W, t);
    for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
    {
        idx = gid_x*W+i;
        Xs[idx] = X[idx] + dt*K[idx]/6;
        Xm[idx] = X[idx] + dt*K[idx]/2;
    }

    //computation of k2
    f(Xm, K, gid_x, W, t);
    for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
    {
        idx = gid_x*W+i;
        Xs[idx] = Xs[idx] + dt*K[idx]/3;
        Xm[idx] = X[idx] + dt*K[idx]/2;
    }   

    //computation of k3
    f(Xm, K, gid_x, W, t);
    for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
    {
        idx = gid_x*W+i;
        Xs[idx] = Xs[idx] + dt*K[idx]/3;
        Xm[idx] = X[idx] + dt*K[idx];
    }   

    //computation of k4
    f(Xm, K, gid_x, W, t);
    for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
    {
        idx = gid_x*W+i;
        Xs[idx] = Xs[idx] + dt*K[idx]/6;
    }

    //update photon
    for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
    {
        idx = gid_x*W+i;
        X[idx] = Xs[idx];
    }
}
```

If i comment this line:

```
aux = (X[(id-1)*W+6] + X[(id+1)*W+6]);
```

The code runs through with no errors, but if I uncomment it, i get the error i described.

The python code that calls this kernel is the following:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

"""
Solve the problem
Xi' = M1*Xi + M2*Xi~
M1 and M2 are 6*6 Matrixes which elements are complex numbers
Xi in the form [P11i, P22i, P33i, P21i, P31i, P32i, Ai] where Pxyi is a complex number
""" 

########################################################
#                                                      #
#'_h' buffers are host buffers. '_d' are device buffers#
#                                                      #
########################################################

#Initialization of the device and workspace
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
MF = cl.mem_flags

# Constants 
M = 2000 # Number of atoms
L = np.float32(0.000000001) # Atom Spacing
N = 1000 # Number of time intervals
dt = np.float32(0.1) # Time interval
Timeline = np.arange(0.0, N, dt).astype(np.float32) 
p0 = np.float32(1.0) # constant P0 [OMP = P0*Ai]
delta = np.float32(1.0) # constant DELTA
gama = np.float32(1.0) # constant GAMA
omc = np.float32(1.0) # constant OMC

# Writing the source code with the constants declared by the user
text = ""
##text = "__constant int M=" + str(M) + "; \n"
##text += "__constant float L=" + str(L) + "; \n"
##text += "__constant float dt=" + str(dt) + "; \n"
##text += "__constant float p0=" + str(p0) + "; \n"
##text += "__constant float delta=" + str(delta) + "; \n"
##text += "__constant float gama=" + str(gama) + "; \n"
##text += "__constant float omc=" + str(omc) + "; \n"
f1 = open("precode.cl", "r")
f2 = open("kernel.cl", "r")
f3 = open("source.cl",'w+')
precode = f1.read()
kernel = f2.read()
f3.write(precode + text + kernel)
f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()

#Initial Conditions 
A_h = (np.arange(M) + 1j*np.zeros(M)).astype(np.complex64)
A_h = np.exp(-((A_h-M/2.0)/(0.05 * M))**2)*np.exp(1j * 200.0 * A_h /M)

P11_h = (np.random.randn(M) + 1j*np.random.randn(M)).astype(np.complex64)
P22_h = (np.random.randn(M) + 1j*np.random.randn(M)).astype(np.complex64)
P33_h = (np.random.randn(M) + 1j*np.random.randn(M)).astype(np.complex64)
P21_h = (np.random.randn(M) + 1j*np.random.randn(M)).astype(np.complex64)
P31_h = (np.random.randn(M) + 1j*np.random.randn(M)).astype(np.complex64)
P32_h = (np.random.randn(M) + 1j*np.random.randn(M)).astype(np.complex64)

W = np.uint32(7) # The row width to compute the index inside the kernel
X_h = []
for i in range(M):
    X_h.append( np.array([P11_h[i], P22_h[i], P33_h[i], P21_h[i], P31_h[i], P32_h[i], A_h[i]]).astype(np.complex64) )
X_h = np.array(X_h).astype(np.complex64)
K_h = np.empty_like(X_h)
Xs_h = np.empty_like(X_h)
Xm_h = np.empty_like(X_h)

A_h = X_h[:,6]
figure(1)
plt.plot(np.real(A_h))
plt.plot(np.abs(A_h))

# Allocation of required buffers on the device
X_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=X_h)
K_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=K_h)
Xs_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=Xs_h)
Xm_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=Xm_h)

f = open("source.cl", "r")
source = f.read()
f.close()
prg = cl.Program(ctx, source).build()

print "Begin Calculation"
start_time = time.time()

for t in Timeline:
    completeevent = prg.RK4Step(queue, (M,), None, X_d, K_d, Xs_d, Xm_d, W, t)
    completeevent.wait()

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, X_h, X_d)
end_time = time.time()
print "All done"
print "Calculation took " + str(end_time - start_time) + " seconds"

A_h = X_h[:,6]
figure(2)
plt.plot(np.real(A_h))
plt.plot(np.abs(A_h))
##plt.show()
```

Some code is commented because I'm still working on it but it's minor stuff just to get things a bit cleaner.

I can't understand why this happens. I've tried something similiar but with a much simpler code and the neighbors access goes just fine as I intended.
For examples, when I run this module:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
MF = cl.mem_flags

M = 3

zero = np.complex64(0.0)

X1_h = np.array([1 + 1j*2, 2 + 1j*3, 3 + 1j*4]).astype(np.complex64)
X2_h = np.array([1 + 1j*2, 2 + 1j*3, 3 + 1j*4]).astype(np.complex64)
X3_h = np.array([1 + 1j*2, 2 + 1j*3, 3 + 1j*4]).astype(np.complex64)
Y1_h = np.array([4 + 1j*5, 5 + 1j*6, 6 + 1j*7]).astype(np.complex64)
Y2_h = np.array([4 + 1j*5, 5 + 1j*6, 6 + 1j*7]).astype(np.complex64)
Y3_h = np.array([4 + 1j*5, 5 + 1j*6, 6 + 1j*7]).astype(np.complex64)
aux_h = np.complex64(1 + 1j*1)
RES_h = np.empty_like(X1_h)

dados_h = []
for i in range(3):
      dados_h.append(np.array([X1_h[i], X2_h[i], X3_h[i], Y1_h[i], Y2_h[i], Y3_h[i]]).astype(np.complex64))
dados_h = np.array(dados_h).astype(np.complex64)

print dados_h

aux_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=aux_h)
dados_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=dados_h)
RES_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf = RES_h)

Source = """
__kernel void soma( __global float2 *dados, __global float2 *res, int rowWidth){
    const int gid_x = get_global_id(0);
    res[gid_x] = dados[(gid_x-1)*rowWidth] + dados[(gid_x+1)*rowWidth];
}
"""
prg = cl.Program(ctx, Source).build()

completeEvent = prg.soma(queue, (M,), None, dados_d, RES_d, np.int32(6))
completeEvent.wait()

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, RES_h, RES_d)
print "GPU RES"
print RES_h
```

the result i get is:

```
 [[ 1.+2.j  1.+2.j  1.+2.j  4.+5.j  4.+5.j  4.+5.j]
 [ 2.+3.j  2.+3.j  2.+3.j  5.+6.j  5.+6.j  5.+6.j]
 [ 3.+4.j  3.+4.j  3.+4.j  6.+7.j  6.+7.j  6.+7.j]]
GPU RES
[ 2.+3.j  4.+6.j  2.+3.j]
```

which is exactly what i expected.

Can anyone give me some help on what is happening here? It's probably something simple but I can't find what's wrong.

One additional info: This happens only when i run the code on my GTX970. I have a laptop with an old ATI card that handles the code above just fine with no errors, which got me even more confused on this whole thing.

PS: Sorry for the long post

Answer (score 0):

If `id=0` and `W=7` then you use negative index value to access element of 'X' array:

```
aux = (X[(id-1)*W+6] + X[(id+1)*W+6]);
```

which for `id=0` and `W=7` is:

```
aux = (X[-1] + X[13]);
```

From my experience a code with error like this one may produce still good results on some GPUs therefore I always test my opencl code using different GPU vendors. Especially opencl validation on CPU seems to be very sensitive to such errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
What I don't understand is why the second piece of code works on my GTX970 but the first kernel doesn't when adding the neighbors. 
And now that i think about it, when I do:
    al = X[(id-1)*W+6];
    ar = X[(id+1)*W+6];
I don't get any error on the first cl code, but when I add them, it crashes.

Comment: `al = X[(id-1)*W+6];ar = X[(id+1)*W+6];` is a dead code and is removed by optimizer. In out of bound access you may not always get a crash because the read can be successful and it can be either the garbage value or value of other variable which resides in the memory before the beginning of the array.